# 6 Vertical Line CSS below a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make 6 CSS vertical lines under a table. I have attached a screenshot of what I need to achieve. Can someone help me with this one please.

[image]

```
<div id="tablebar">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1960</th>
            <th>1970</th>
            <th>1980</th>
            <th>1990</th>
            <th>2000</th>
            <th>2010</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The css:

```
  tr:after {
   content: '';
   width: 0;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid black;
   top: 0;
   left: 100px;
  }
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/du2670h6/)?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Almost what I want . I need the first and last table cell with full screen vertical line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with it, is this what you're after?

```
#tablebar table{
    width:100%;
} 
#tablebar table thead tr th {
    position:relative;
}
#tablebar table thead tr th:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    left:50%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:100%;
 }
#tablebar table thead tr th:first-child:after,#tablebar table thead tr th:last-child:after {
    height:900%;
}
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gametroll/zmdzwz4p/1/)

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you very much for your prompt response. That does the job, thank you,  although I have small problem the first and the last vertical line should go over my content. I can see the line but under my content . Can you please help me this .

Comment: You could play with the z-index of the :after section. Setting it to 1 might be enough to pull it in front of later dom content.

Comment: Thanks! Have fun coding. :)